# Finding extreme values using Lagrange multipliers given constraint

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, lagrange-multiplier

Find the extreme values of the function subject to the given constraint.$$f(x,\, y) = y^2 - x^2,\, x^2 + y^2 = 16$$

I understand how to to compute the extrema using Lagrange multipliers and lambda however I keep getting this question wrong. I end up with 
$$-2x=λ*2x$$
$$2y=λ*2y$$

Comment: Looks OK so far. What’s the problem?

Comment: oh really? Well thats good haha in THAT case can you point me to what I would need to do next?

Comment: On the given constraint we have $f(x,y)=16-2x^2$ so the problem is quite trivial, no need for Lagrange multipliers. Stationary points occur at $x=0$ and $x=\pm 4$. We also have $\min f=-\max f$ since the constraint is symmetric wrt to $x,y$ while $f(y,x)=-f(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first equation $-2x=\lambda\cdot 2x$ implies that either $x=0$ or $\lambda=-1$ (or both).

Your second equation $2y=\lambda\cdot 2y$ implies that either $y=0$ or $\lambda=1$ (or both).

Combining those two, you have a total of four possibilities. Look at each possibility and find the possible points (if any) for that possibility. Then look at the function values at each resulting point. Use those to find the maximum and minimum values of your function.

Comment: So essentially, $$x^2+y^2=16$$ I would just plug 0 for values x and y and the answer would be 16 therefore maximum 16 and minimum 16?

Comment: @EconDude: Not quite. You cannot have both $x=0$ and $y=0$ (remember $x^2+y^2=16$) nor have $\lambda=1$ and $\lambda=-1$, so you have $x=0, \lambda=1$ or $y=0, \lambda=-1$ as your only actual possibilities. So your points are $(0,4),(0,-4)$ for the first and $(4,0),(-4,0)$ for the second. Now calculate the function values at those four points.

Comment: Oh okay max 16 and min -16, thanks Rory!